# Bit shift with float number

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-shift

I want to shift 10 bits of a float number end store value in an integer. But i have a problem.

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int lastValue;
    float myNum = -29.33;
    lastValue = myNum * (1 << 10);
    cout << lastValue << endl;
}
```

however `lastValue` is `false`, where am I wrong?

Comment: please pick one language. Your code does not return anything (apart from the implicit `return 0;`) What is the issue?

Comment: Could you detail what result you expect in this example? Not clear for me what you intend to do.

Comment: I want to lastValue is true. @damien

Comment: Which value did you get? Which value did you expect?

Comment: `lastValue` is an `int`. What does it mean when you say "it is false" ?

Comment: You're not bitshifting a float. You're just multiplying a float with the integer value `(1<<10)`

Comment: Convert first, then shift. Note that "convert" is more subtle than it might appear.

Answer (score 2):

`lastValue` is defined as an `int`. Its truth value is `false` if it is `0` and `true` otherwise.

`lastValue = myNum * (1 << 10);` is evaluated as:

```
lastValue = (int)(myNum * (float)(1 << 10));
```

which produces `(int)(-29.33F * 1024.0F)`, hence approximately `(int)-30033.92`.

The output should be `-30033`, which is true if used in a test.